# Disable an entire form in js without individually disabling each field

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, field, disable

I have created a form using JSF. There are many accordion panels in my form and each accordion panel consists of several fields.

I wanna disable all the fields of one such accordion panel using js. Instead of individually disabling each field of the accordion panel, is there a shortcut method to disable the whole accordion panel all at once.

Comment: Disabling with JS is actually not disabling. Clients can easily enable them again and if you disable them on the client, the server still thinks they are enabled and tries validating them etc.... Better to look for something like http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute

Comment: And since there is no JSF on the client this question is effectively (if you really want to disable in the client), **not** JSF related

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to all of the form fields and then select the fields with that class.

Once you have the DOM reference then you could loop over the form fields and disable.

**Demo:**

```js
function disableForm() {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".form-elements");
    for (const elem of elems) {
        elem.disabled = true;
    }
}

function enableForm() {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".form-elements");
    for (const elem of elems) {
        elem.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
<label>Element 1</label><br />
<input type="text" class="form-elements" /> <br />
<label>Element 2</label> <br />
<select class="form-elements"> <br />
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<br />
</form>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="disableForm()">Disable Form</button>
<button type="button" onclick="enableForm()">Enable Form</button>
```

Comment: by adding a class element to each field, will it affect the UI of the form ?

Comment: "Setter not found for property class" error coming up after I assign this class to each element

Comment: ill have to use styleclass instead of class. But on some of the inputText panels, style class is being already used for different purpose eg:

Comment: <p:outputLabel for="contactPersonNo"
    value="Contact Person Number" />
   <p:inputText id="contactPersonNo123" styleClass="textbox" 
    value="#{xyz..contactPerson}" 
    maxlength = "10"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="Value is Required">
    <p:keyFilter preventPaste="false" regEx="/[\d\-\.]/" />
   </p:inputText>

Comment: Add one you class in it like this. `<p:outputLabel for="contactPersonNo" value="Contact Person Number" /> <p:inputText id="contactPersonNo123" styleClass="textbox someOtherClass" value="#{xyz..contactPerson}" maxlength = "10" required="true" requiredMessage="Value is Required"> <p:keyFilter preventPaste="false" regEx="/[\d\-\.]/" /> </p:inputText>`

Comment: how can i use multiple characteristicts for one styleClass ?

Comment: You could add multiple classes

Comment: the JS will remain same as told by you above ?

Comment: what issue are you getting now ?

Comment: its working fine but some combobox values are not getting disabled. I had to pass their individual widgetVar values outside the loop and then they got disabled.